# Php/Regex get the contents between a set of double quotes

Tags: php, regex

Update to my question:
My goal overall is to split the string into 4 parts that I can access later.

1. value
2. =
3. "
4. result of the html inside the first and last "  "

Here is an example of what i'm trying to do:

// My string (this is dynamic and will change, this is just an example)

```
$string = 'value="<p>Some text</p> <a href="#">linky</a>"';
```

// Run the match and spit out the results

```
preg_match_all('/([^"]*)(?:\s*=\s*(\042|\047))([^"]*)/is', $string , $results);
```

// Here is the array I want to end up with

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => value="<p>Some text</p><a href="#">linky</a>"
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => value
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => "
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => <p>Some text</p><a href="#">linky</a>
    )
)
```

Basically the double quotes on the link are causing me some trouble so my first though was to do [^"]$ or something to have it just run until the last double quote, but that isn't getting me anywhere.  Another idea I had was maybe process the string in PHP to strip out any inner quotes, but i'm not sure ho to go about this either.

Hopefully I'm being clear, it is pretty late and i've been at this far too long!

Comment: Updated my question with a bit more info, thanks!

Comment: Before you proceed, read this: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html ;-)

Comment: Not much chance of a good answer until you can explain under what circumstances you can know that a double quote doesn't terminate your double-quoted string. Perhaps when you're inside a HTML tag? Concur that regexes aren't really a good solution (you will end up in another twisty maze of corner cases you hadn't thought about).

Comment: Okay, I think I missed the point.  I'm having this issue because the inner quotes are terminating the outer quotes.  So really my best solution would be to escape or remove any double quotes inside the outer quotes?  Is there a way to do that, or am I missing something else, an even bigger point :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do this, because you don't know how which quote marks the end of the string to match and which should be included (especially when there's a variable number of quotes in the values, and more than 1 match in the string). How come are there quotes within quotes anyway? Where does this data come from?

```
$string = 'value="<p>Some text</p> <a href="#">linky</a>"';
```

Just seems very strange to me.

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't thinking straight.  You should never really have double quotes coming inside other double quotes unless they are being escaped.  I'm going to have to re-think this entirely.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't bother changing your html a little bit, you can try this:

```
$string = 'value="<p>Some text</p> <a href=\'#\'>linky</a>"';
```

Comment: Unfortunately the html coming in is dynamic so I don't have control over the inner quotes.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you can use:

```
$string = 'value="<p>Some text</p> <a href="#">linky</a>"';
echo substr( $string, 7, -1 ); //<p>Some texts</p> <a href="#">linky</a>
```

Comment: I'm not too familiar with substr but it looks like it would only work for this example.  Let me update my question stating that the string coming in is dynamic and could change!

Comment: This will work for similar examples, when string begins with «value="» and ends with «"». That is, between the first and last quote could be any characters.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex

```
$string = 'value="<p>Some text</p> <a href="#">linky</a>"';
$regex = '/([^"]*)(?:\s*=\s*(?:\042|\047))(.*)(?:\042|\047)(?:[^"]*)/is';
preg_match_all($regex, $string , $results);
```

it gives following result.

```php
Array(3) {
  [0]=>
  Array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(46) "value="<p>Some text</p> <a href="#">linky</a>""
  }
  [1]=>
  Array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "value"
  }
  [2]=>
  Array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(38) "<p>Some text</p> <a href="#">linky</a>"
  }
}
```

Sincerely